# Layout Design and Color Scheme for a Crisis Mapping Web Application

Tags: website-design, color-theory, critique, maps, cartography

Here are a few screenshots of a web-based crisis mapping software, basically built for both governors and people. The design is somehow combined by ideas from different people, so we are interested to know your ideas, pros and cons of the design choices made there.

**What are the pros and cons of the chosen Color Scheme and the Layout?**

Please consider that at the design goals, it should looks clear and nice yet informative for decision makers, also still nice and easy to explore for a regular person.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why is there so much detail on the terrain and topography in the map? Is it important for your audience? Right now the terrain stands out more strongly than the map markers do, I'd suggest trying to make the terrain more understated. Also, for inspiration on this sort of thing, check out the work of [Development Seed](http://developmentseed.org/) (no affiliation) - they're brilliant at it.

Comment: @user568458 well, you can choose it on the settings to define which type of map should shown there, but we'd add the feature to change that dynamically soon. thanks by the way, we'd mention that to which type of map should be on default. The Development Seed is great also, thank you so much for showing off that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd really have to dig into a working example to assess the UX but, judging from screen caps, it looks great!

I can see how topo would be very useful in certain instances. To @user5684858 point, be mindful of how well your markers separate from all that detail. You might try a slight border on the circles to ensure that they contrast varying backgrounds.

The presentation of the table is a little weak. I'd consider some chrome to make it a little more readable/engaging. Is there any data in there that deserves attention: outliers, mean, etc.?

In the messaging feature, if you use relatively large avatars as shown, I would allocate a little more space for the recipient list. A non-scrolling presentation could work if these lists are likely to be terribly long. Google Plus' implementation of adding people to a circle comes to mind as a good example of this.

It appears to me that your two blues (the header bar and the blue tints used in the body) are not working very well together. They're close but the hue is off slightly: the header moving toward green and the body toward purple.

Comment: Cool man! thanks! I'm in a hurry now, I'd respond you in the next 10-12 hours, which is next day in my local time ... thanks again for the feedback, will write back here with more details :)